# Can i pass an Array element into eq() function

Tags: jquery

Hi can i pass an array element like below

```
 for(var i=0;i<totalNones;i++)
       {
           $(this).children('td:eq(NoneElementsArray[i])').find('input:checkbox').hide();
           alert('I am in ');
           $(this).children('td:eq(NoneElementsArray[i])').append("<input type='radio' class=rad>");
       }
```

It is not working for me. Please someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but currently you are using it as a string. Change it to:

`$(this).children('td:eq('+NoneElementsArray[i]+')')`

Comment: What if NoneElementsArray[i] is an object ?

Comment: @Giann You still wouldn't reference it as a string, it works same way as arrays.